# Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type Number

Tags: actionscript-3

```
        if (goUP == true && player.y > 15 + speedP)
        {
            Tweener.addTween(player, {y:player.y - speedP, time:0.5});
        }
        if (goDOWN == true && player.y < 350 - speedP)
        {
            Tweener.addTween(player, {y:player.y + speedP, time:0.5});
        }
        if (goRIGHT == true && player.x < 120 - speedP)
        {
            Tweener.addTween(player, {x:player.x + speedP, time:0.5});
        }
        if (goLEFT == true && player.x > -365 + speedP)
        {
            Tweener.addTween(player, {x:player.x - speedP, time:0.5});
        }
```

WHAT I AM MISSING HERE?
I am trying to make a player move  up down left right

Comment: First of all, you should turn debugging on and narrow the question to the single line that gives you the error. Since these lines are all alike, it is either condition or something inside **addTween(...)**. That, of course, if the error is not originated from some code outside the provided snippet.